# Non-angular AJAX library use in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, api, trello

I am having some trouble incorporating Client.js for the Trello API into my app, it is a wrapper for http requests, I was wondering if I should list it as a dependencies in my service or in my main app module. (the wrapper is just called Trello)

data service:

```
(function(){
  angular
   .module('trelloThere')
   .service('trelloData', trelloData);

   trelloData.$inject = ['$http'];
   function trelloData ($http) {
     var getToken = function(options){
    return Trello.authorize(options); 
    };

  var getTangs = function(){
   return Trello.get(path,success);
    };

  return {getToken: getToken,
          getTangs: getTangs
          };
       };
})()
```

In my index.html file, I have the trello api script declared with my app key after jquery (listed as necessary in docs) so that isn't the issue.

However, I have ngSanitize and ngRoute declared as external modules in my app.js file:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('trelloThere', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);

  config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
  function config ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
         controller: 'homec',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
     .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
     $locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false
    });
  }

angular
 .module('trelloThere')
 .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', config]);

})()
```

should I insert 'Trello' into that array with ngSanitize and ngRoute?

Is simply having it in my index.js file enough and now I am free to use it anywhere in the app ? (the latter would mean theres just an error somewhere in my controller which I could deal with) thanks